# 20amp 12/2 wire with 14/2 switch?

Tags: electrical

Installing  new bathroom heater/fan combo which requires a dedicated 20amp circuit. I got that 12/2 wire ran direct to the breaker.... the problem is the fan that was existing had a switch that I was planning on reusing for this new one. Only it is 14/2 wire, is it ok to run from the junction box in the new heater/fan the main power which will be the 12/2 AND the 14/2 for the existing switch?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not OK. All the wire on the circuit must match or exceed the breaker size based on the type of circuit it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is allowable, but since there is any 14 AWG wire, it is a 15A circuit.

That means you must use a 15A breaker.

In bathrooms, new work requires 20A circuits and special rules as to what else can be on a circuit that feeds bathroom receptacles.  However, these "new work" rules apply only to new construction and serious remodels; certainly not a fan replacement.

By the way, if you were to replace the switch loop with 12/2, you must use 12/3 instead, to comply with the new rules requiring neutral to be provisioned to switches.  it would be better to run even more conductors to control fan and heater separately, but 12/4 is the largest size of NM cable reasonably available.  You can't run 2 cables because current can't go down one cable and come back the other.

Comment: Apparently the fan/heater is beefy enough to need 20A all by its lonesome...perhaps a relay could be used here?